# Contineous_cast c variadic alias. Попытка номер 2

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Все таки мой прошлый вопрос с похожим названием был больше про распаковку `std::any`, в этот раз я действительно пытаюсь сделать сам `contineous_cast`. В общем суть в том что после некоторого количества арифметических операций с объектами типа `std::variant<some sequence...>` в итоговом объекте лежит результат с обобщенным `common_type`, то есть самым большим по размеру типом из варианта и теперь необходимо его скастовать к оптимальному типу. Моя задача сводится к тому, чтобы попасть в диапазон между переполнением с предыдущим типом и валидным текущим и присвоить первый валидный тип полю `type`. Моя попытка это сделать свелась к такому наброску, но я даже не пытался это компилировать, потому что мне кажется что такие форматы распаковки не допустимы. Тем не менее основную идею они иллюстрируют.

```
template <class ...>
struct contineous_cast_helper;

template <
    class A,
    class C,
    C value,
    class Suitable = std::enable_if_t< (value < std::numeric_limits<A>::max() )>
    >
struct contineous_cast_helper {
    type = A;
};

template <
    class A,
    class B,
    class C,
    C value,
    class NotSuitable = std::enable_if_t< (value > std::numeric_limits<A>::max())>,
    class Suitable = std::enable_if_t< (value < std::numeric_limits<B>::max())>
    >
    struct contineous_cast_helper {
    type = B;
};

template <
    class ...Rest,
    class A,
    class B,
    class C,
    C value,
    class NotSuitable = std::enable_if_t< (value > std::numeric_limits<A>::max() )>,
    class Suitable = std::enable_if_t< (value < std::numeric_limits<B>::max() )>
    >
    struct contineous_cast_helper {
    type = B;
};

template <
    class ...Rest,
    class A,
    class B,
    class ...Rest2,
    class C,
    C value,
    class NotSuitable = std::enable_if_t< (value > std::numeric_limits<A>::max())>,
    class Suitable = std::enable_if_t< (value < std::numeric_limits<B>::max())>
    >
    struct contineous_cast_helper {
    type = B;
};

template <class ...Rest, class A, class B, class C, C value>
using contineous_cast = contineous_cast_helper<...Rest, A, B, C, value>::type;

template <class ...Rest, class A, class B, class ...Rest2, class C, C value>
using contineous_cast = contineous_cast_helper<...Rest, A, B, ...Rest2, C, value>::type;

int main () {
 long long a = 200; // some common type
 using b_type = typename contineous_cast<int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, long long, a>::type;
 static_assert(is_same_v<b_type, int16_t>) // should be valid
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так. Но это работает только с числами, которые являются константами времени компиляции, потому что тип должен определяться во время компиляции.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Чем меньше число, тем "лучше" тип.
template <typename T>
inline constexpr std::size_t type_rank = sizeof(T) * 2 + std::is_unsigned_v<T>;

template <auto> struct value_tag {};

// Возвращает тип из списка по его "рангу".
// `R` = `value_tag<ранг>`.
template <typename R, typename ...P> struct get_type_by_rank {};
template <typename T, typename ...P> struct get_type_by_rank<value_tag<type_rank<T>>, T, P...> {using type = T;};
template <typename R, typename T, typename ...P> struct get_type_by_rank<R, T, P...> {using type = typename get_type_by_rank<R, P...>::type;};

// Проверяет, что `X` представимо типом `T`.
template <auto X, typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_representable = []{
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<decltype(X)> && std::is_integral_v<T>);
    return !std::is_signed_v<T> && X < 0 ? false : X == T(X);
}();

// Кастует `X` к минимальному типу из `P...`.
template <auto X, typename ...P>
inline constexpr auto cast_to_smallest = []{
    constexpr std::size_t min_rank = []{
        std::size_t min_rank = -1;
        ([&]{
            if (type_rank<P> < min_rank && is_representable<X, P>)
                min_rank = type_rank<P>;
        }(), ...);
        return min_rank;
    }();
    return typename get_type_by_rank<value_tag<min_rank>, P...>::type(X);
}();

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const unsigned char, decltype(cast_to_smallest<     0, unsigned char, short, int>)>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const unsigned char, decltype(cast_to_smallest<   255, unsigned char, short, int>)>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const short        , decltype(cast_to_smallest<   256, unsigned char, short, int>)>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const short        , decltype(cast_to_smallest< 32767, unsigned char, short, int>)>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int          , decltype(cast_to_smallest< 32768, unsigned char, short, int>)>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const short        , decltype(cast_to_smallest<    -1, unsigned char, short, int>)>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const short        , decltype(cast_to_smallest<-32768, unsigned char, short, int>)>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int          , decltype(cast_to_smallest<-32769, unsigned char, short, int>)>);
}
```

Comment: Супер. [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/eE6d9n4no) не захотел компилировать только, а _сlang_ успешно. Ради интереса, можно заменить fold-expression из лямбд на **return ((min_rank = type_rank<P> < min_rank && is_representable<X, P> ? type_rank<P> : min_rank), ...);**. А почему во второй специализации  **get_type_by_rank** значение **type_rank<T>** оборачивается в **std::size_t**, если оно и так этого типа, и без этого не компилит?

Comment: @magrif *"почему во второй специализации ... оборачивается в std::size_t"* Сам точно не понял.

Comment: @magrif Поколдовал, теперь и гцц собирает.